# Did Riddick make the trip to the Underverse

Tags: riddick-franchise, the-chronicles-of-riddick

It states in [Riddick Wiki, Lord Marshal](http://riddick.wikia.com/wiki/Lord_Marshal) that each one is to make the trip to the Threshold,

> Since Covu "The Transcended" discovered the gate to The Underverse, called "The Threshold", each successive Lord Marshal has made a pilgrimage to The Underverse. His trip to The Underverse grants him a plethora of greater inhuman powers. All The Lord Marshals are extremely long lived, perhaps even immortal.

In the next section it states that Zhylaw "The Last" finds an artifact, but it does not imply that this artifact shows the way to The Threshold, only its secrets.

> Zhylaw "The Last" discovered a great ancient artifact on Helion Prime, within the secrets of The Threshold were written, after studying and destroying the artifact so that nobody could ever find it, he would use it in his great crusade. With this knowledge he could use more of the Soulpower than any other Lord Marshal making him the most powerful Lord Marshal in history.

In [Riddick](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1411250/) , Riddick does not display any of the powers of a lord Marshal, so it would be safe to assume that he did not go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, as of the events of [*Riddick*](http://riddick.wikia.com/wiki/Riddick_(film)), he has not transcended nor acquired the powers of a Lord Marshal. Indeed, at the beginning of the film, we learn that, in the time between the ending of Chronicles and the 'present', Riddick has essentially avoided much of the responsibility of his position, to the degree that he hasn't even sworn himself to the Necromonger faith, let alone led the fleet to the Threshold.

This has prompted an understandably (given the tenets of the Necromonger culture) large number of assassination attempts on his life, the last of which incited him to make a deal with Vaako. In exchange for providing Riddick with the location of, and transport to Furya, Vaako would be given the mantle of Lord Marshal.

The deal is struck, and, although we learn that Vaako's intention was, indeed, to make good on this promise, his subordinate, Krone, charged with taking Riddick to Furya instead takes him to the planet where the film largely takes place. Of course, our goggled protagonist manages to survive this assassination attempt as well, along with the subsequent events of the film, bounty hunters and all.

HOWEVER, in the extended, director's cut of the film, we learn a bit more regarding this subject. After the main events of the film, we find Riddick back at the Necromonger fleet, undoubtedly having snuck aboard the Necropolis in the usual manner. Finding Krone, he demands to know the whereabouts of Vaako. Outside the ship, the phenomenon implied to be the Underverse Threshold can be seen, and between the swiftly-killed Krone and a slave, we learn that Vaako is no longer living or dead, suggesting that he has transcended and acquired the aforementioned powers. It's implied, then, that Riddick seeks to follow for his own purposes, but we can't know for sure what happens beyond this point.

Sources:

[*Riddick* wiki.](http://riddick.wikia.com/wiki/Riddick_(film))

[Wikipedia's *Riddick* page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddick_(film))

Watching the film itself. I have probably watched *Chronicles* too many times.

Comment: You yourself must have transcended in order to see something enjoyable in *Chronicles*.

Answer (score 0):

The start of the Underverse is a galaxy that is shrouded in a dark form of power, even if you had traveled to the place the actual gifts are hidden within. It's true that the Lord Marshals gifts come from there but their power comes from within. to achieve the rank one would have to find a special circumstance to apply for such status, they're known as lord marshal's and each person is close enough to get it